# Existence of a global completion functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Is there any such thing as a ``global completion functor'' for commutative Noetherian rings?

More specifically, let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring.  For each maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, let $W_m := R \setminus m$. I want a Noetherian ring $S$ and a ring homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ such that for each maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, the localized map $\phi_m: R_m \rightarrow W_m^{-1} S$ is isomorphic to the $mR_m$-adic completion map $R_m \rightarrow \widehat{R_m}$.  Does such a thing exist?

I guess from a geometric point of view, I want a scheme $X$ over Spec $R$ whose closed fibers correspond to adic completion.

Comment: Your requirement at the closed point is on the stalks, so it imposes some non-trivial constraints at non-closed points too. In fact, they're so strong that such a ring (noetherian or not) cannot exist for $R=\mathbf{Z}$ already. Indeed, if such an $S$ existed, then for any prime number $p$, the base change along $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}_{(p)} \to \mathbf{Q}$ would have to give $\mathbf{Z}_p[1/p] = \mathbf{Q}_p$. But this is true for all $p$, so we must have $\mathbf{Q}_p = \mathbf{Q}_\ell$ as fields for all primes $p$ and $\ell$, which is not true (e.g., by roots of unity).

Comment: Maybe I'm off-base, but I'd have thought that however you precisely formulate the question, the canonical example of a "global completion" should be getting $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$ from $\mathbb Z$, so maybe the issue is in the formalization of the question?

Comment: @Anonymous Wait a minute.  Why does it follow that $\mathbb Q_p = \mathbb Q_\ell$?

Comment: You can base change along $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Q}$ by going through either $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ or through $\mathbf{Z}_{(\ell)}$. The former gives $\mathbf{Q}_p$ while the latter gives $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$.

Comment: Hm.  I guess you are using that $\mathbb Z_p \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q_p$, right?  I don’t quite see why that tensor product has to be a field — just that it has to contain $\mathbb Q_p$ as a subring.

Comment: Base changing from $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Q}$ amounts to inverting all the primes, so it takes $\mathbf{Z}_p$ to $\mathbf{Q}_p$ (as once you invert $p$, nothing needs to be done).

Comment: Okay.  Thank you!  Post this as an answer, and I’ll accept it.

Comment: @TimCampion Thank you.  It’s an interesting idea, but for the application I have in mind, I think $\prod_m \widehat{R_m}$ does not do what I want.

Comment: @NeilEpstein Okay. But I wasn't necessarily suggesting you use $\prod_m \widehat{R_m}$ in general. Only that whatever definition you settle on, it should agree with $\prod_m \widehat{R_m}$ when $R = \mathbb Z$. Perhaps it's wrong even in this case, in which case I have misunderstood your intention.

Comment: @TimCampion Well I didn't say what I wanted it for, so there's no way you could know.  But yeah, I don't think even $\hat {\mathbb Z}$ does what I want.